# can not read property 'arrowHead' of undefined error occurs in my code for polyline arrow in leaflet

Tags: javascript, asp.net, leaflet

```
var somePoints = [];

for (var rowIndex in rows) {

    somePoints.push(L.latLng(rows[rowIndex].Lat, rows[rowIndex].Lon));
}

var pl = L.polyline(somePoints);

pl.addTo(map);

var decorator = L.polylineDecorator(pl, {
    patterns: [
        {offset: 0, repeat: 50, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 8, polygon: false, pathOptions: {stroke: true}})}
    ]
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file did you import the polylinedecorator script,

```
<script src="../dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js"></script>
```

as in here? https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator/blob/96858e837a07c08e08dbba1c6751abdec9a85433/example/example.html#L17)

Sounds stupid but I scratched my head multiple times with this error.